# php ploting series for highcharts heatmap

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => oct
            [value] => 10
            [state] => MU
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => nov
            [value] => 29
            [state] => MU
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => oct
            [value] => 88
            [state] => DL
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => nov
            [value] => 67
            [state] => DL
        )

    )
```

above is my php mysql response.

for highchart heatmap month is plotting on x axis and state is plotting on y axis.

I have question for how to mapping value for series of heatmap.
see heatmap series plotting like [[0,0,10],[0,1,29]] etc....
see below link

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/

I have to plot series by using php.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample code:

```
<?php
$states = ['DL','BL','MU','OU'];
$data_array = [['month' => 'oct', 'value' => 10, 'state' => 'MU'],['month' => 'jan', 'value' => 12, 'state' => 'OU']];

$graph_array = [];
foreach ($data_array as $data){
    $state = array_search($data['state'], $states);
    $month = date('n',strtotime($data['month']));
    $graph_array[] = [$state,$month,$data['value']];
}

print_r($graph_array);
```